# How to create, share and run python programs with pip and virtualenv

Tags: python, deployment, virtualenv, pip, dependency-management

I have created my program using virtual env. It is working in my project folder fine. Now i need to take this program and release it to the production environment that is supposed to be accessible by everybody.So  this program should be  runnable as is or it might be incorporated into other programs as a step. How am i supposed to deploy it? Zip the whole project folder? Is it possible to do without requiring clients to copy it and then unzip and run? Or the only way is to create a commonly accessible script that automates unzipping of the thing and configuring virtual env and then running it or there is a smarter way?

More complicated scenario is when it supposed to be used as library. How to deploy it so others could specify it as their dependency and pick it up? Seems like the only way is to create your own PyPi-like local repository - is that correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what i have found:

If we have a project A as API:

1. create a folder where you will store the wheels (~/wheelhouse)
2. using pip config specify this folder as one to find links in http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/configuration.html

i have:

```
[global]

[install]
no-index = yes
find-links = /home/users/me/wheelhouse
```

Make sure the wheel package is installed.

1. In your project create setup.py file that will allow for the wheel creation and execute

   python setup.py bdist_wheel

copy the generated wheel to the wheelhouse so it has:

```
~/wheelhouse/projectA-0.1-py33-none-any.whl
```

Now we want to create a project that uses that projectA API - project B

we are creating a separate folder for this project and then create a virtual environment for it.

```
mkdir projectB; cd projectB
virtualenv projectB_env
source projectB_env/bin/activate
pip install projectA
```

Now if you run python console in this folder you will be able to import the classes from the projectA! One problem solved!

Now you have finished the development of projectB and you need to run it.
For that purpose I'd recommend to use Pex (twitter.common.python) library. Pex now supports (v0.5.1) wheels lookup as dependencies. I'm feeding it the content of requirements.txt file to resolve dependencies. So as the result you will get the executable lightweight archived virtualenv that will have everything necessary for the project to run.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

- http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/
- http://guide.python-distribute.org/
- http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/

Comment: Thanks, but http://guide.python-distribute.org/future.html#inshort

setup.py gone!
distutils gone!
distribute gone!
pip and virtualenv here to stay!
eggs ... gone!

Comment: Sorry I thought you asked for how to distribute your program _now_, not in some unpredictable future. Good luck chap.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the pip and virtualenv is supposed to help me in distribution and deployment if they can at all. I know how to create egg files, but it is not what i'm asking. As far as i understand the idea behind virtual env is to be able to create, maintain and distribute the program together with the env that can be easily reconstructed anywhere. Otherwise it seems there would be no sense to have it developed  in one env and then deploy it to completely different one where you can't guarantee it will work.

Comment: The idea behind virtualenv is first and mainly to have an isolated Python environment. Then using pip and distribute/setuptools you can indeed recreate the same environment, but there's no automated creation of the venv itself so far (nor of the required Python version). pip itself relies on distribute/setuptools to install the packages FWIW.